# Add colon (:) after every 2nd character using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and want to add a colon after every 2nd character (but not after the last set), eg:

> 12345678

becomes

> 12:34:56:78

I've been using `.replace()`, eg:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(.{2})/g, NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE)
```

but none of the regex for `:` I've used work and I havent been able to find anything useful on Google.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are examples of it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Second match on Google for me...

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way but you can try `array.map`. `str.split().map(function(item){ if(str.indexOf(item)%2==0 && str.indexOf(item)>0){return ":" + item} else return item; })

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(..)/g, '$1:').slice(0,-1)
```

This is what comes to mind immediately. I just strip off the final character to get rid of the colon at the end.

If you want to use this for odd length strings as well, you just need to make the second character optional. Like so:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(..?)/g, '$1:').slice(0,-1)
```

Comment: I think that only one set of grouping parentheses is required? Is there a reason for the second set? i.e. `/(..)/g, '$1:'` seems to work just as well.

Comment: @mhawke You're right, not sure why the extra ones are there

Answer (score 12):

Without the need to remove any trailing colons:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/..\B/g, '$&:')
```

`\B` matches a zero-width non-word boundary; in other words, when it hits the end of the string, it won't match (as that is considered to be a word boundary) and therefore won't perform the replacement (hence no trailing colon, either).

`$&` contains the matched substring (so you don't need to use a capture group).

Comment: this should be an accepted answer as its more succinct (without slice version), no?

Comment: Also, not part of question but assuming this question was asked to convert mac addresses, one would want to make sure its a 12-character mac string using `mystring.padStart(12, "0").replace(<above answer>)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for approach other than RegEx, try this:

```
var str = '12345678';
var output = '';
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  output += str.charAt(i);
  if(i % 2 == 1 && i > 0) {
    output += ':';
  }
}
alert(output.substring(0, output.length - 1));
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07gq0zu9/)

Answer (score 2):

Easy, just match every group of up-to 2 characters and join the array with `':'`

```
mystring.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':')
```

```js
var mystring = '12345678';

document.write(mystring.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':'))
```

no string slicing / trimming required.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat different approach without regex could be using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```
Array.prototype.reduce.call('12345678', function(acc, item, index){
    return acc += index && index % 2 === 0 ? ':' + item : item;
}, ''); //12:34:56:78
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = mytring.replace(/(.{2})/g, '\:$1').slice(1)
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you tweak what you're searching for to avoid an end-of-line colon(using negative lookahead regex)

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(.{2})(?!$)/g, '\$1:');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(.{2})/g, '$1\:')
```

Give that a try

Comment: Thanks for the fix @Evan :)

Comment: This results in `"12:34:56:78:"`

Answer (score 0):

I like my approach the best :)

```
function colonizer(strIn){
  var rebuiltString = '';
  strIn.split('').forEach(function(ltr, i){
    (i % 2) ? rebuiltString += ltr + ':' : rebuiltString += ltr;
  });
  return rebuiltString;
}

alert(colonizer('Nicholas Abrams'));
```

Here is a demo

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjjNJj